# how to show that $f(x)=3x^{2/3}$ is not lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to prove that $f(x)=3x^{2/3}$ is not lipschitz continuous: but I'm not sure what to do, the derivative criteria does not work around 0 and when I try to use an argument by contradiction I arrive nowhere.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you mean that $\;2/3\;$ to be an exponent?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. I just edited your post to fix the display of the exponent; take a look how I did this (right-click on the formula). As to your question, if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on some interval $[a,b]$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|/|x-y|$ cannot go to $\infty$ as $y \to x$. Rather this ratio will remain bounded. Now try this for some fixed $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slope becomes unbounded at 0, where the derivative blows up.

Suppose for the sake of insanity that 
$$
\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{|x|}\leq M
$$
For any x. Then 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{|x|}\leq M\Rightarrow |f'(x)|\leq M\Rightarrow |\frac{2}{x^{2/3}}|\leq M
$$
For all x, a clear contradiction, since this would imply that $x^{2/3}$ doesn't tend to 0 as x tends to 0.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Does there exist a real number $M$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq M|x - 0|$ for all real $x$?